# How to fix special characters when the title or excerpt is shortened

Tags: title, excerpt

I have this code for the title

```
<?php $thetitle = $post->post_title; $getlength = strlen($thetitle); $thelength = 26; echo substr($thetitle, 0, $thelength); if ($getlength > $thelength) echo "..."; ?>
```

And this for the excerpt

```
<?php $content = get_the_content(); $content = strip_tags($content); echo substr($content, 0, 89); ?>...
```

Everything works correctly, except when the last letter is a special character, because then I get this � (Malformed byte sequence).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`mb_substr()`](https://php.net/mb_substr()%60), which is safe to use on multibyte strings. I ran a quick test on my local installation of PHP:

```
php > $str = 'éééééé';
php > var_dump( substr( $str, 0, 3 ) );
string(3) "é�"
php > var_dump( mb_substr( $str, 0, 3 ) );
string(6) "ééé"
php > var_dump( mb_substr( 'abcdef', 0, 3 );
string(3) "abc"
```